# Cauchy Integral Formula of $\int_C \frac{z^3+3}{z(z-i)}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I'm trying calcualte this integral $\int_C \frac{z^3+3}{z(z-i)}dz$ when the path $C$ is something similar to
$$C=\gamma_1+\gamma_2$$,
where $\gamma_1:|z-i|=1$, $\gamma_2:|z+i|=1.$

My solutions is choose $f(z)$ as $f(z) = \frac{z^3 + 3}{z}$ but $f$ is not analytic on the path, I don't know how choose the function because $i$ is inside of the curve $C$ then I think that my unique choose of $f$ it's the one I gave before.

Can you give me a hint on how to proceed?

Comment: Another method: $$\frac{z^3+3}{z(z-i)}=z+i+\frac{3-z}{z^2-iz}$$
, and $\int_C (z+i)\mathrm{d}z=0$, it suffices to determine the latter term.
Suppose $a,b\in\mathbb{C}$ satisfies $\frac{a}{z}+\frac{b}{z-i}=\frac{3-z}{z^2-iz}$, then try to determine $a,b$. Then, $\int_C \frac{a}{z}\mathrm{d}z$ and $\int_C \frac{b}{z-i}\mathrm{d}z$ should not be hard to solve.

Comment: @Asigan thanks, I understand. I only have a doubt when calculating the integral $\int_c\frac{a}{z}$, because $0$ is in the path C

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that. Then your teacher/textbook may have given you a question with typo. The function definitely needs to be defined everywhere on the curve to do the intergration.